# Why do I get an error when I enter input? "expression: string subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, string

I get an error when I try to enter input for my implementation of a Lorenzo decoding machine:

> expression: string subscript out of range

Why?

also i am loading in a .dat file which has the pin settings in it.

Here's a section where i think the error lies, within my code:

```
    string chi (string pinSettings, string code, int count)
    {

 if (count = 0)
 {
        chi1 = 0,;
 }

 compare1 = code[0];
 if (chi1 + 351 >= 391)
{
chi1 = 0;
}
compare2 = pinSettings[chi1 +351];

int result = (compare1 - '0') ^ (compare2 - '0');


compare1 = code[1];

if (chi2 + 392 >= 423)
{
    chi2 = 0;
}


chi1 ++;
chi2 ++;

string fPass;
fPass += (result+'0');
fPass += (result2+'0');

return fPass;
    }

    bool mu (string pinSettings, int count)
    {
char compare1;
char compare2;
static int mu61, mu37;

if (count = 0)
{
mu61 = 0, mu37 = 0;
}

if (mu61 + 290 >= 351)
{
mu61 = 0;
}

compare1 = pinSettings[mu61 +290];
int compareInt1 = (compare1 - '0');
mu61++;

if (compareInt1 == 1)
{
    mu37 ++;
    if (mu37 + 253 >= 290)
    {
          mu37 = 0;;
    }
    compare2 = pinSettings[mu37 + 253 - 1];
    int compareInt2 = (compare2 - '0');

    if (compareInt2 == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}


    }

    string psi (string pinSettings, int count, bool rotate, string code2)
    {
char compare1;
char compare2;
static int psi1, psi2, psi3, psi4, psi5;

if (count == 0)
{
psi1 = 0, psi2 = 0, psi3 = 0, psi4 = 0, psi5 = 0;
}

if (rotate == true)
{
    psi1++;
    psi2++;
}

compare1 = code2[0];
if (psi1  >= 43)
{
psi1 = 0;
}
compare2 = pinSettings[psi1];


int result = (compare1 - '0') ^ (compare2 - '0');


compare1 = code2[1];

if (psi2 + 43 >= 90)
{
    psi2 = 0;

}

compare2 = pinSettings[psi2 + 43];

int result2 = (compare1 - '0') ^ (compare2 - '0');



string fPass;
fPass += (result+'0');
fPass += (result2+'0');

return fPass;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code a bit? You could have tried to narrow it down a bit..

Comment: yeahh that's WAY too much code

Comment: ok just going through now to try and narrow down the code

Comment: i think it's pretty obvious that "string subscript out of range" means that a string subscript was out of range. and you have lots of subscript expressions like `pinSettings[psi5 + 194]`. have you considered that the string might be, like, **too short**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a debugger. You don't say what platform you are developing on but common ones are Microsoft Visual Studio, Mac OS X and Linux.

In Visual Studio run in Debug mode. Set the debug settings to stop on a C++ exception.

In Linux use GDB. Compile with `gcc -ggdb -O0`, run with `gdb ./program` and enter `catch throw` then `run`.

In OS X I forget the exact steps but they are similar to Visual Studio. You can also use GDB from the command line once you've installed the developer tools.